# How to make border around material ui grid items only

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    border: '4px solid green',
    display: 'inline-flex',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container justify="center" className={classes.container}>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd like my border to be around only the two items in the Grid container. Currently the border takes up the full width of the container. Even after adding inline-flex to parent container, it doesn't change the border taking full width.

Answer (score 1):

You just to create in your function useStyle, on the return object :

```
container: {
    border: '4px solid green',
    display: 'inline-flex',
  },
  item: {borderRadius: 30px}, 
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
```

and put :

```
<Grid item xs={4} classeName={classes.item}>
```

It's simple so I have a doubt about my capacity to understand your problem, if, please comment.